# section a datetime column by just dates, not time

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have two dataframes. Dataframe 1 is indexed by a DATETIME column.

The format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Dataframe 2 has just one column, a list of select Dates in format: YYYY-MM-DD

I want to section Dataframe 1 by the dates in Dataframe 2.

I am not sure how to get R to ignore the HH:MM:SS section of Dataframe 1's DATETIME column

I tried `match(meetingDates$Date, days1993$DATETIME)`
but returned a bunch of NA's

I also tried to add a new column to Dataframe 1 that is just the Date portions of the DATETIME column `days1993$DATE <- ymd(days1993$DATETIME)` but it didn't work.

```
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Any advice?

Comment: `as.Date(days1993$DATETIME)` will convert that column to date only, dropping the time of day.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be sure of the problem without a reproducible example (there are a couple of possibilities), but try putting `as.Date()` around the column in Dataframe 1.  See below for a demo of how this might work:

```
> x1 <- strptime("2012-06-15 12:15:42", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> x2 <- as.Date("2012-06-15")
> x1
[1] "2012-06-15 12:15:42 NZST"
> x2
[1] "2012-06-15"
> x2 == x1
   sec    min   hour   mday    mon   year   wday   yday  isdst   zone gmtoff 
 FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE     NA     NA 
Warning messages:
1: Incompatible methods ("Ops.Date", "Ops.POSIXt") for "==" 
2: NAs introduced by coercion 
> x2 == as.Date(x1)
[1] TRUE
```